# Selenium not performing button click using ID - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on Google Search button but selenium is not working in my case.

`driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("India");` is working but `driver.findElement(By.id("gsr")).click();` is not working.

Alternate way can be `driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` but i want to perform button click only. Any reason why it is not working?

```
private static void performButtonClickWithId() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("India");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("gsr")).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're picking wrong `ID`. The `gsr` is ID for the whole `<body>` of google page, you should rather do:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
```

which seems to be the name attribute of the search button. See the pic below:
[image: Search button]

Answer (score 1):

First Your id for search is incorrect, second, you can use XPath or name as suggested by @Pijotrek

Some of the xpath are as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search' and @name='btnK']")).click();
```